# How to add params an array of values inside getStaticPaths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, content-management-system, sanity

I have a page it structure is the following : `/read/[slug]/[number]`
I want to get the `slug` value that corresponds each `number` in the `getStaticPaths`
This is the code :

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const slugs = await client.fetch(
    `*[_type == "comic" && defined(slug.current)][].slug.current`
  )
  
  const paths = await client.fetch(
    `*[_type == "comic"][].chapters[].number`
  )

  return {
    paths: paths.map((number : any) => ({params: {number: number, slug: "test"}})),
    fallback: false,
  }
  
}
```

the `slugs` variable is the array that contains all the slug values.
instead of `test` in the params slug value , I want to get it corresponding value of `number` , how I can possible manipulate this code to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to map on both arrays in the same time, something like this will do it:

```
paths
    .map((number: any) =>
      slugs.map((slug: any) => ({ params: { number, slug } })))
    .flat(); // to avoid nested arrays
```

one thing though, I recommend to avoid the `any` type since it defeats the purpose of using typescript